# Como resolver problema de JSON.parse usando Ionic e AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Estou com o seguinte erro a seguir e não consigo solucionar:

Erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 142
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (forma_pag_cad_controller.js:24)
```

A string é este resultado:

```
{"nome":"Dinheiro"}{"nome":"Cheque"}{"nome":"Cart\u00e3o - Cr\u00e9dito  - VR Benef\u00edcios"}{"nome":"Cart\u00e3o Aura - Cr\u00e9dito"}
```

Meu código:

```
// LISTA FORMAS DE PAGAMENTO    
    $scope.formapag = [];

    $scope.getformaspag = function () {
        $scope.formapag = [];
        $ionicLoading.show();       
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var responseishere = xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (responseishere == "error") {
                    $scope.nothing = 1;
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                } else {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    var myobj = JSON.parse(responseishere);
                    for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
                        $scope.formapag.push(myobj[i]);
                    }
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/vovo/cadastro_vovo/lista_formPag.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    $scope.getformaspag();
```

Já mudei o formato do Json, mas continua com o erro.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

UPDATE: Segue meu PHP:

```
    <?php


header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-32"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';

//$cod_fornecedor=$_GET['cod_fornecedor'];


$query="SELECT
   nome
FROM
   formas_pagamento
ORDER BY
   cod_forma_pagamento ASC";


$result=$con->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e coloque a `string` do `json` que está tentando parsear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu formato JSON está incorreto, porém há também um ponto de falha grande aí, se uma dessas chamadas à função [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) falharem  dentro do seu loop while, seu programa irá gerar uma string inconsistente também.

Além disso, a função [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) tem um [custo alto para a performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize) da sua aplicação, é melhor realizá-la apenas uma vez.

> NOTA: Usar uma vez apenas irá reduzir o consumo de CPU para processar
>   porém elevará o uso de memória. O uso dentro de um loop como está
>   sendo feito [usará mais CPU e menos memória](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize) porém é mais passível
>   de falhas de sintaxe.

A solução mais segura é você acumular os resultados num array e então realizar por fim o [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) apenas uma vez com o resultado e então imprimindo os dados num formato json válido gerado pela própria função nativa.

```
<?php


header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-32"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';

/*** (...) ***/

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    //$count=0;
    $dados = array();
    //echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        array_push($dados,$row);
         /* $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }
        */

    }
    //echo "]";
    $jsonstr = json_encode($dados);
    //Irá retornar nulo se falhar
    if (!$jsonstr) {
            switch (json_last_error()) {
                case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                    $msgError = ' - No errors';
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                    $msgError = ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                    $msgError = ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                    $msgError = ' - Unexpected control character found';
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                    $msgError = ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                    $msgError = ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
//                    var_dump($obj);
                    break;
                default:
                    $msgError = ' - Unknown error';
                    break;
            }
            throw new Exception($msgError, json_last_error());
        } else {
            echo $jsonstr;
        }
}
else
{
echo "[]"; //Use um array vazio para que seu resultado seja mais coeso entre o erro e um resultado vazio. Valide no javascript usando o ".length" do retorno.
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema deve ser o formato do seu arquivo JSON está errado.

Ao validar através do site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, o erro encontrado é com relação a virgula e aspas simples no final do arquivo, o json correto deve ficar desta forma.

```
[{"nome":"Dinheiro"},{"nome":"Cheque"},{"nome":"Cart\u00e3o - Cr\u00e9dito  - VR Benef\u00edcios"},{"nome":"Cart\u00e3o Aura - Cr\u00e9dito"}]
```

Altere o arquivo JSON, isto deve solucionar.